# Angular localization messages.en.xlf source and target same content

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-cli, angular-i18n

I have built couple of angular applications and I used i18n to create localization files. The problem with it is, whenever I change something in html, I need to update the xlf file also, as xlf has line numbers of the tags. When I re-generate the file I have to copy and paste the target tags for english file again.

I am trying to see if there is a command which generates the xlf file where source and target are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There definitely is. I've used xliffmerge --profile xliffmerge.json for this specific scenario and it works perfectly.

There is a good tutorial on how to use this here: https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/wiki/Tutorial-for-using-xliffmerge-with-angular-cli